# How do I get a array to just count how many numbers there are instead of counting the value of each number?

Tags: c++

This is the output of the program :

```
*** start of 276 2D Arrays_03.cpp program ***

Number    Count     Total
   1        3         3
   2        6         9
   3       15        24
   4        6        30
   5        9        39

*** end of 276 2D Arrays_03.cpp program ***
```

---

This is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const int COLUMN_SIZE = 13;

int main(void)
{
    const int ROW_SIZE = 3;
    const int COUNT_SIZE = 5;

    void countValues(const int[][COLUMN_SIZE], const int, int[]);
    void display(const int [], const int);

    int numbers[ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE] = {{1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2},
                                    {2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3},
                {3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 5}};

    int counts[COUNT_SIZE] = {0};
    string choice;

    cout << "*** start of 276 2D Arrays_03.cpp program ***" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    countValues(numbers, ROW_SIZE, counts);

    display(counts, COUNT_SIZE);

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "*** end of 276 2D Arrays_03.cpp program ***" << endl << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}   // end main()
```

This is the function where I need to count each of the values.  I know how to sum rows and cols, but I'm not quite sure of the code to just tally the values themselves.

```
void countValues(const int numbers[][COLUMN_SIZE], const int ROW_SIZE, int counts[])
```

This is what I have so far.

```
{
 for (int index = 0; index < ROW_SIZE; index++)
  counts[index];
{
```

Comment: Is this homework? How come midnight GMT marks a sudden onset of homework? Hmmm....

Comment: Yes it is, but its not due until next week just wanted to get it out of the way.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It helps us (and you) to show us how far you got and what approach you are taking.

Answer (score 1):

i'll not do your homework for you, but maybe this will help you:

you have an array "counts" ...
the index of each element in that array corresponds to your values ...

if you itterate over your values, you can easily find the corresponding array element for your current value

remember that arrays start counting at 0, but your values start counting at 1

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems this is your homework, and it doesn't seems like its worth trying to theach you how to write good code, while you're at this level, so I'll just post the corected code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// if you declare these here, you don't need to pass ROW_SIZE as a parameter
const int COLUMN_SIZE = 13;
const int ROW_SIZE = 3;
const int COUNT_SIZE = 5;

// you should declare functions in the global scope
void countValues(const int[][COLUMN_SIZE], int[]);
void display(const int [], const int);


int main(void)
{    
    int numbers[ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE] = {{1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2},
                                    {2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3},
                {3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 5}};

    int counts[COUNT_SIZE] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; // <-- you should init all the five elements since COUNT_SIZE is 5 in your code
    string choice;

    cout << "*** start of 276 2D Arrays_03.cpp program ***" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    countValues(numbers, counts);

    display(counts, COUNT_SIZE);

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "*** end of 276 2D Arrays_03.cpp program ***" << endl << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}   // end main()

void countValues(const int numbers[][COLUMN_SIZE], int counts[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWSIZE; ++ i)
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; ++ j)
        {
            ++ counts[numbers[i][j] + 1];
        }
}
```

by the way, I wrote some comments for you, so you sould delete those from your final work